# Spelling error in release notes

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, spelling

The iOS latest version of the SE app's release notes has a spelling error:

> The achievement bar button item will now stay in it's designated area

The word *it's* is misspelled; there should be no apostrophe.

- "its" is the possessive form of "it"
- "it's" is a contraction of "it is", or of "it has" when "has" is an auxiliary verb, eg "it has been fun" -> "it's been fun"

It's a quality thing.

Pedantic? Well, wrong is wrong.

---

I realise that this can't be "fixed", since the ship has sailed. "Fixed" probably means that "done" now includes having someone proofread SE-produced content.

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s

Comment: I am completely with you on this. Precision is important in computation.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.  These types of issues will likely crop up from time to time since I just hastily throw the list together when shipping the app.  The alternative is, "Thank you for using our app.  Please turn on automatic updates for blah, blah, blah."